# Get oneToMany field from class with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I want to retrieve from database a list of properties for an Entity but I get the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class MapClass
```

My Entitiy:

```
 public class Entity{

     //properties

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   private List<Profile> profiles = new LinkedList<Profile>();

   public Entity(){}

 }
```

Mapping class:

```
 public class MapClass{

     //properties


   private String name;
   private List<Profile> profiles ;
   public MapClass(String name,List<Profile> profiles){
     this.name = name;
     this.profiles = profiles;
   }

 }
```

My sql query :

```
String sql =  "SELECT new MapClass(u.name,u.profiles) FROM Entity u";
return getList(MapClass.class,sql);
```

My query WORKS if I remove profiles from MapClass Constructor and from query. I have empty constructors in all my classes.

Comment: Create empty constructor for `MapClass`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate needs a constructor for working: add it in your class

```
public class Entity{

    //add the constructor
    public Entity(){ }

}
```

Comment: I already have the constructor added. It works with other fields other than List<Something>.

Comment: @Tobi that wasn't present in the original question. Do you also have a constructor in the `Something` class? IE in your `List<Profile>` ? Do you also have an empty constructor in `MapClass` ? That error refers exactly to missing constructor

Comment: Yes, I have empty constructor in all my classes. :(

Comment: Well, only apply empty constructors on beans, ie. classes that are annotated as "@Entity" @Tobi

Answer (score 0):

Empty constructor is a requirement for Hibernate. It uses a reflection on this constructor to instantiate required objects.

```
   //empty constructor
    public Entity(){

    }

  //empty constructor
    public Profile(){

    }
```

Create empty constructors in your entity beans, ie. classes annotated as `@Entity`.